# Android-Java Client-Server - Toast in AsyncTask crashing application

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, client-server, toast

I have 2 applications which are communicating through an AsyncTask. The first application is a Java server, running on my PC. The second application is an Android Client.

The server send to the client a message like that :

> " 1stMember , 2ndMember , 3rdMember , ... , 10thMember "

Then, the Client retrieve this message in the innerclass **connectTask** from the client class.
But the application is always crashing.

This is my client **MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private TCPClient tcpclient;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Connect to server - See innerClass connectTask below
        new connectTask().execute("");
    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient>
    {
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message)
        {
            // Creation of TCPClient object...
            tcpclient=new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() 
            {
                public void messageReceived(String message) 
                {
                    publishProgress(message);
                    /*==> publishProgress receive message, then notify onProgressUpdate*/
                }
            });
            tcpclient.runClient();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            showMySelectedValues(values[0].toString());     
        }
    }

    public void showMySelectedValues(String values)
    {
        String[]selectedvalues=values.split(",");
        Log.i("LENGTH OF selectedvalues... : ",""+selectedvalues.length);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedvalues[3],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedvalues[5],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }   
}
```

Before crashing, the application still shows me the toast.
**Here is my Logcat :**

[image]

```
12-11 16:09:33.070: D/dalvikvm(11798): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 12% free 9455K/10695K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
12-11 16:09:35.914: I/LENGTH OF selectedvalues... :(11798): 12
12-11 16:09:35.945: I/LENGTH OF selectedvalues... :(11798): 12
12-11 16:09:35.953: I/LENGTH OF selectedvalues... :(11798): 12
12-11 16:09:35.976: I/LENGTH OF selectedvalues... :(11798): 1
12-11 16:09:35.976: D/AndroidRuntime(11798): Shutting down VM
12-11 16:09:35.976: W/dalvikvm(11798): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4104f2a0)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=3
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at com.fiamm.tcpandroid.MainActivity.showMySelectedValues(MainActivity.java:154)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at com.fiamm.tcpandroid.MainActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:145)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at com.fiamm.tcpandroid.MainActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:1)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
12-11 16:09:35.984: E/AndroidRuntime(11798):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the **Debuger**:
[image]

When I do this in onProgressUpdate(String...values), it is not crashing :

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedvalues[3],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But when I **make more than 1 toast**, then the **application is crashing again**.

I don't understand what is wrong in my code. Can someone help me please ?

In advance, thank you.

Best regards,

Tofuw

Comment: Use handler to show your toast message. It is recommended to show toast message and alert dialog in UI thread.

Comment: Are you sure `selectedvalues[3]` isn't null?

Comment: Hi @Apoorv, I've already debugging my Application, and selectedvalues[3] isn't null.

Comment: @Tofuw post the stack trace.

Comment: Hi @RethinavelPillai, thank you for your answer. Like I'm still not at ease with Android, can you advise me for an example please ?

Comment: @Tofuw check length  of `String[]selectedvalues`. log the values and then use the index to display in toast

Comment: @Tofuw what is the length of `selectedvalues`. can you log that value and post it here. I don't think so coz the log is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=3
```

Length is 1. Array index starts from 0.

The length of `selectedvalues` is 1. You are trying to access `selectedvalues[3]`.

Comment: Can you please look at my last Picture please ? Because I've just verify the length of selectedvalues, and apparently there are 12 elements in. But I'll look again what you've just told me.

Comment: @Tofuw `Log.i("..............",""+selectedvalues.length)` check the length in log

Comment: You are right, at the end, selectedvalues has a length of 1. I don't understand why.

Comment: I've just debug it. I've posted the final result. Have you got an idea about it ? Thank you

Comment: @Tofuw you go it wrong. `publishProgress(message)`. message is string. then you split `String[]selectedvalues=values.split(",");` Now the length is 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42968/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tofuw)

Comment: @Tofuw join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42968/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tofuw

Comment: I've just solved it. For my test, I only send 3 messages to the Client. It is like messageReceived(String message) is receiving a fourth one. It is bit of cheating, but I've add a condition before doing the toast : `if(selectedvalues.length>1)`.
Thanks to all of you for help me ! :)